# ListChildren recursively in sightly

Tags: recursion, aem, sling, sightly

There is one method of Page interface which can be used in sightly to iterate through children.

I want to iterate all the subsequent children reccursively.

there is an overloaded method listChildren(Filter ,Boolean) which can do that ......how to call this method from sightly??
I mean how Should onemodify the tag mentioned above to do it recursively.

Answer (score 14):

You may define a [`data-sly-template`](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/sightly-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#2291-template), which is some kind of macro, and then call it recursively with [`data-sly-call`](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/sightly-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#2292-call):

```
<template data-sly-template.descendants="${@ page}">
    ${page.title}
    <ul data-sly-list.child="${page.listChildren}">
      <li data-sly-call="${descendants @ page=child}"></li>
    </ul>
</template>

<div data-sly-call="${descendants @ page=currentPage}" data-sly-unwrap></div>
```